# React native with UWP - How to setup react-native UWP environment?

Tags: react-native, uwp, windows

### I have a specific requirement to use react native for creating app for windows devices using the UWP. I googled about react native for windows with UWP support then i followed https://github.com/ReactWindows/react-native-windows

my 
NPM version: 2.15.9

### Node version: 4.6.1

**commands i followed:**

choco install nodejs.install

npm install -g react-native-cli

react-native init AwesomeProject

cd AwesomeProject

npm install --save-dev rnpm-plugin-windows

react-native windows

then i got the below error

E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1>react-native windows
E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:176
          throw new ReferenceError(messages.get("pluginUnknown", plugin, loc, i, dirname));
          ^

ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-flow-strip-types" specified in "base" at 0, attempted to resolve relative to "E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native-windows\local-cli"
    at E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:176:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at Function.normalisePlugins (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:154:20)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:228:36)
    at OptionManager.init (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-core\lib\transformation\file\options\option-manager.js:373:12)
    at compile (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:103:45)
    at loader (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:144:14)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1\node_modules\react-native\node_modules\babel-register\lib\node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)

[React native ref](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is related to the version of NPM that you are using. You should be using at least npm@3.*. Try upgrading with `npm upgrade npm@latest`.

After that, you'll want to remove the `node_modules` folder and re-run `npm install` in your project directory.

Comment: E:\reactApps\myapp\sample1>npm -v
3.10.8

Comment: thats my current npm version, but still it didnt work